# Why are there local variable conflicts in my recursive function definition?

Tags: recursion, scoping, procedural-programming

Sorry to post a long piece of code. There are two places in here where I Print[] 'path2' when the `count == 984`, because for some reason, that list is getting truncated in between those two points. I can only guess that there's some kind of conflict of local variables between calls to the function `tryNext`.  But I'm at a lost to prevent it.

This codes searches for a Knight's Journey on a chessboard, a path that makes knight moves covering the entire board and returns where it started. `ks` is a list of legal knight-steps. The algorithm actually starts two paths at `{1, 1}` and extends them both out one step at a time until one can't move anymore or until they have covered all 64 squares and are one knight-step apart.

`chCorners` is just a time-saver that forces the search to handle the board corners correctly and not search dead ends. For example, if the knight lands on `{6, 7}`, he has to go to `{8, 8}` and `{7, 6}` immediately or he will never be able to hit the `{8, 8}` corner.

`tryNext` calls itself recursively adding a step to both paths with each recursion.  And, for some reason, `path2` gets truncated between the two places I print it, but I can't figure out why.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];

ks = {{-2, -1}, {-2, 1}, {-1, -2}, {-1, 2}, {1, -2}, {1, 2}, {2, -1}, {2, 1}};

chCorners[kp_] :=
  Switch[kp,
    {2, 6}, {{2, 6}, {1, 8}, {3, 7}},
    {3, 7}, {{3, 7}, {1, 8}, {2, 6}},
    {6, 2}, {{6, 2}, {8, 1}, {7, 3}},
    {7, 3}, {{7, 3}, {8, 1}, {6, 2}},
    {6, 7}, {{6, 7}, {8, 8}, {7, 6}},
    {7, 6}, {{7, 6}, {8, 8}, {6, 7}},
    _, {kp}];

tryNext[p1_, p2_] := 
   Module[{path1 = p1, path2 = p2, lp, ns1, ns2, np1, np2},
     count = count + 1;
     ns1 = Table[Last[path1] + ks[[i]], {i, 1, 8}]; (*All possible next steps on path1*)
     ns2 = Table[Last[path2] + ks[[j]], {j, 1, 8}]; (*All possible next steps on path2*)
     If[count == 984, Print[Length[path2], " a ", path2]]; (*Where the bug happens*)
     Do[
       (*Check that we haven't found a solution, the next step being examined is actually on the chessboard and hasn't been visited already on either path1 or path2*)
       If[
         (! done) && (0 < ns1[[i, 1]] < 9) && (0 < ns1[[i, 2]] < 9) &&
          ! (MemberQ[path1, ns1[[i]]] || MemberQ[path2, ns1[[i]]]),
         np1 = Join[path1, chCorners[ns1[[i]]]];
         lp = Length[np1] + Length[path2] - 1;
         If[(count == 984), Print[Length[path2], " b ", path2]]; (*Where the bug happens*)
         done = (lp == 64) && MemberQ[ks, Last[np1] - Last[path2]];
         If[lp < 64,
           Do[
             If[
               (! done) && (0 < ns2[[j, 1]] < 9) && (0 < ns2[[j, 2]] < 9) && 
                ! (MemberQ[np1, ns2[[j]]] || MemberQ[path2, ns2[[j]]]),
               np2 = Join[path2, chCorners[ns2[[j]]]];
               tryNext[np1, np2]] (*Both paths okay so far but not yet connected; press on*), 
             {j, 1, 8}]]], 
       {i, 1, 8}]];

(*Starting point of program*)
done = False;
count = 0;
(* Starting two paths from lower left corned, {1,1} *)
tryNext[{{1, 1}, {2, 3}}, {{1, 1}, {3, 2}}];
```

Comment: That's a lot of code without any explanation! Please describe what your goal is, the approach you took, and how you implemented that approach.

Comment: @MarcoB  Thank you.  Okay, I added explanation.  I think my basic approach is right, I just have some local variable conflict.

Comment: @Somos  You maybe think it's a bug in MMa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your debug statments are misleading. You also need to track recursive call levels. That requires some extra code. Add a statement `level++;` right before `count = count + 1;` and at the last line of `tryNext[]` replace with `{i, 1, 8}]; level--];`. Next print out the `level` in your two `Print[]` statements and finally, add `level = 0;` in the initialization code.

The first "a" print output is at level 28 and the two "b" print outputs are at level 22. Thus, it is no wonder that `path2` is not the same. In other words, the value of `count` only tracks the number of times you enter the function from the "top" but doesn't track when the function returns from a previous call so that `count` is still the same, but `level` has been decremented.

Comment: Oooooooooh!  Thank you so much for putting the time into this, because I was absolutely stumped.  I modified the code to pass in and pass along a 'level', and it played out exactly as you said.